# sphinx-build command not found in gitlab ci pipeline / python 3 alpine image

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci, python-sphinx, alpine-linux

I want to specify a GitLab job that creates a sphinx html documentation.

I am using a Python 3 alpine image (cannot specify which exactly).

the build stage within my  `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like this:

```
pages:
  stage: build
  tags: 
  - buildtag
  script:
  - pip install -U sphinx
  - sphinx-build -b html docs/ public/
  only:
  - master
```

however, the pipeline fails: `sphinx-build: command not found`. (same error for `make html`)

According to [This Tutorial](https://gitlab.com/pages/sphinx/-/blob/master/README.md), my `.gitlab-ci.yml` should be more or less correct.

What am I doing wrong? Is this issue related to the alpine image I am using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Yasen correctly noted, the path to `sphinx-build` was not contained in `$PATH`. However, adding `command` in before `sphinx-build` did not solve the problem for me.

Anyway I found the solution in the the runner logs: The output of `pip install -U sphinx` produced the following warning:

`WARNING: The scripts sphinx-apidoc, sphinx-autogen, sphinx-build and sphinx-quickstart are  installed in 'some/path' which is not on PATH.`

so I added `export PATH="some/path"` to the script-step in the `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
script:
  - pip install -U sphinx
  - export PATH="some/path"
  - sphinx-build -b html docs/ public/
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the reason is that `$PATH` doesn't contain path to `sphinx-build`

### TL;DR try to use `command`

Try this:

```
pages:
  stage: build
  tags: 
  - buildtag
  script:
  - pip install -U sphinx
  - command sphinx-build -b html docs/ public/
  only:
  - master
```

### Explanation

#### `GitLab` runners run different way

Since `GitLab CI` uses [`runners`](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/), `runner`'s shell profile may differ from commonly used.

So, your runner may be configured without declared `$PATH` to the directory that contains `sphinx-build`

#### Zsh/Bash startup files loading order (.bashrc, .zshrc etc.)

See [this explanation](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/):

> The issue is that Bash sources from a different file based on what kind of shell it thinks it is in. For an “interactive non-login shell”, it reads .bashrc, but for an “interactive login shell” it reads from the *first* of .bash_profile, .bash_login and .profile (only). There is no sane reason why this should be so; it’s just historical.

#### What `command` does mean?

Since we don't know the path where `sphinx-build` installed, you may use commands like: `which`, `type`, etc.

As per this great answer([shell - Why not use "which"? What to use then? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85250/145897), author recommends to use `command <name>`, or `$(command -v <name>)`

Comment: Unfortunately, your proposed solution did not work for me. With `command sphinx-build` i got the same error again. But indeed it was a problem with PATH (see my answer)

Answer (score 1):

Did the command `pip install -U sphinx` succeed? (You should be able to tell that from the CI job log.)

If so, you may need to specify the full path to `sphinx-build`, as Yasen said.

If it did not succeed, you should troubleshoot the installation of Sphinx.